# jQuery clone elements without id

Tags: jquery, clone

How can i change the id while cloning?

Example:

```
<div id="unique" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique1" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique2" class="cloneMe">test</div>
```

Script

```
jQuery('.cloneMe').clone(); // has all selected after cloning
  ...
```

Result

```
<div id="unique" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique1" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique2" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique1" class="cloneMe">test</div>
<div id="unique2" class="cloneMe">test</div>
```

How can i explicitly modify only the cloned div?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `each` and then set a new id.

```
jQuery('.cloneMe').clone().each(function(i){
  this.id = "id"+ i; // to keep it unique
}).appendTo("someSelector");
```

Comment: *facepalm*. Thanks however :)

Comment: @PeterRader clone only returns cloned elements so, there's nothig wrong.